# How to run multiple commands using terraform local-exec

Tags: terraform, azure-cli, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to run a few az cli commands using terraform using local-exec provisioner but I keep running into an error that says:

```
Error: Invalid expression

On modules/eventgrid/main.tf line 68: Expected the start of an expression, but
found an invalid expression token.
```

Here's my code:

```
resource "null_resource" "eg-role-assignment" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    
    interpreter = ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
    command = <<EOT 
              "az account set --subscription foo"
              "az eventgrid topic update --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP --name $EVENTGRID_NAME --identity systemassigned"
    EOT

    environment = {
      RESOURCE_GROUP = "RG_${var.platform_tag}_${var.product_code}_PUBLISH_${var.environment}_${var.location_code_primary}"
      EVENTGRID_NAME = "EG-${var.platform_tag}-${var.product_code}-${var.environment}-${var.location_code_primary}-domain"

    }
  
  }
}
```

Can anybody please guide me as to what's wrong ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With your `<<EOT` statement, you're inside a string literal already, so you don't need the quotes. Also, `<<-EOT` (with a dash) is indentation aware, while `<<EOT` is not.

Finally, as the cause of the issue, you have a space after `EOT`.

```
command = <<-EOT
          az account set --subscription foo
          az eventgrid topic update --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP --name $EVENTGRID_NAME --identity systemassigned
EOT
```

Comment: Hello @Dan Monego! Thanks for that suggestion. However, I'm still running into the same issue. Is there anything else I might be missing out on ?

Comment: Ah! You had an extra space on your heredoc anchor - `<<-EOF ` instead of `<<-EOF`. That was the root issue.

Comment: The answer's been updated to remove the extra whitespace.