# Deploy docker-compose in Azure Container Apps with Terraform

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, terraform, azure-container-apps

I have a docker-compose file intended to use [traefik](https://traefik.io/traefik/) alongside my docker image that I want to deploy as an Azure Container App with terraform.

I looked for answers to this and all I found is how to create the container app using the CLI as referenced in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70594846/deploy-docker-compose-on-azure-container-app). But looking in docs for Azapi or Azurerm I didn't find anything referencing this.

So far my docker-compose looks like this:

```html
version: '3'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:v2.10
    command:
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"  # Define the web entry point on port 80
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

  form-service:
    image: "XX.azurecr.io/form-service:latest"

    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app1.rule=Host(`localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/app1`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app1.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app1.service=app1"
      - "traefik.http.services.app1.loadbalancer.server.port=3031"

      - "traefik.http.routers.app2.rule=Host(`localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/app2`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app2.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app2.service=app2"
      - "traefik.http.services.app2.loadbalancer.server.port=3032"

    environment:
      - LOG_LEVEL=trace
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

> I have a docker-compose file intended to use [traefik](https://traefik.io/traefik/) alongside my docker image that I want to deploy as an Azure Container App with terraform.

To create an `Azure Container App` with your own `Docker` image, ensure that you push the `Docker image` to `Azure Container Registry` before creating the `container app`.

To pull from a container registry, you may need **'acrpull'** access using the `identity method`. Ensure that you enable the **'Admin user'** in `Azure Container Registry` before proceeding. Additionally, you need role assignment access to assign the **'acrpull'** role to the `user-assigned identity`.

I created a sample **Docker image** and `pushed` same image to my `ACR`.

[image]

Terraform code to create a `Azure container app` with `Docker` image.

```json
    provider "azurerm"{
        features {}
    }
    
    data "azurerm_resource_group" "my_rg" {
      name     = "Resource_Group"
    }
    
    data "azurerm_container_registry" "demo-acr" {
      name                = "venkatacrdemo"
      resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.my_rg.name
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "container_identity" {
      location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.my_rg.location
      name                = "user_assigned_containerapp"
      resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.my_rg.name
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "container_role" {
      scope                = data.azurerm_container_registry.demo-acr.id
      role_definition_name = "acrpull"
      principal_id         = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.container_identity.principal_id
      depends_on = [
        azurerm_user_assigned_identity.container_identity
      ]
    }
    
    
    resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "container_law" {
      name                = "container-law"
      location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.my_rg.location
      resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.my_rg.name
      sku                 = "PerGB2018"
      retention_in_days   = 30
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_container_app_environment" "ca_env" {
      name                       = "Containerenvironment"
      location                   = data.azurerm_resource_group.my_rg.location
      resource_group_name        = data.azurerm_resource_group.my_rg.name
      log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.container_law.id

    }
    
    resource "azurerm_container_app" "containerapp" {
      name                         = "demo-container-app"
      container_app_environment_id = azurerm_container_app_environment.ca_env.id
      resource_group_name          = data.azurerm_resource_group.my_rg.name
      revision_mode                = "Multiple"
     
      identity {
        type         = "UserAssigned"
        identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.container_identity.id]
      }
     
      registry {
        server   = data.azurerm_container_registry.demo-acr.login_server
        identity = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.container_identity.id
      }
     
    
      template {
        container {
          name   = "containerappacr"
          image  = "venkatacrdemo.azurecr.io/sample_docker_image/react_application:v1"
          cpu    = 0.25
          memory = "0.5Gi"
     
          readiness_probe {
            transport = "HTTP"
            port      = 80
          }
     
          liveness_probe {
            transport = "HTTP"
            port      = 80
          }
     
          startup_probe {
            transport = "HTTP"
            port      = 80
          }
        }
      }
     
    }
```

**Terraform apply:**

[image]

The `Container App` has been created with reference to my `Docker` image.

[image]

Refer to the [Stack Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77041834/azure-container-apps-and-terraform-issue/77044815#77044815), where I provided the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however my question is about "docker-compose" and not a simple container-app running a docker image.

Comment: Currently Terraform does not support for directly deploying docker-compose files to Azure Container Apps.

Comment: If you want to create using Terraform, you can utilize the 'null_resource' in Terraform's code and execute Azure CLI commands. This approach allows you to create a Container app with a composefile. Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68957371/how-to-run-multiple-commands-using-terraform-local-exec